# AWS machine-readable API description

Tags: amazon-web-services, schema

Google APIs have published human-readable documentation and also machine-readable JSON schemas, for instance https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/urlshortener/v1/rest. I am looking to auto-generate API clients for AWS cloud services for a language that does not currently have an API client. For this, I need a machine-readable description of these APIs.

Is there such a schema available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the AWS sdks work in this way, for example the ruby sdk includes [json descriptions](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/master/apis) for all of the API methods, arguments and return values.

I don't know if this representation is considered public (in the sense that newer versions don't change this schema) but it should be possible to generate an API client from it given that this is how the ruby sdk is built.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has JSON service descriptions [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data) for all AWS services. These are automatically generated and kept up-to-date from the AWS backend, and consumed by the official `aws-cli` and Python library `Boto3`.